# Laravel multiple joins using scope to check every record if it has a value

Tags: mysql, laravel, join, eloquent

I have 3 tables, the first is '**Event**' table with columns:

```
id
showname
eventdate
office_id   //the office that made this
photo
user_id   //the user that saved the record
...
```

and some other columns.

The office_id is foreign key in offices below

The second is '**Offices**' table

```
id
name
address
owner_id  //the user owner of Office
...
```

and some other columns.

The owner_id is foreign key in Users below

and the third is 'Users' table

```
id
name
...
```

and some other columns.

Now I am trying in an index view file to show the events.

I made that using a scope in Events model that showed the Events that belongs to the signed_in User.

```
public function scopeHasMyOffice($query, $me)
{
    return $query->join('offices', function ($join) use ($me) {    
        $join->on('events.foffice_id', '=', 'offices.id')
             ->where('owner_id', $me);
    });        
}
```

In the controller, I wrote this code

```
public function myindex()
{
    $my = Auth::User()->id;

    if (!is_null($my))
    {
        $events = Event::HasMyOffice($my)->select('events.*')
                                         ->orderby('eventdate', 'desc')
                                         ->get();              
    }
    else
    {
        $events = NULL; 
    }    
}
```

That works and gives the list of the events whose owner is the user connected.

I have 2 other lists that show all events of the state and the city.

Now I want to show in front of every row a button 'View' that is easy and a button 'Edit' if the event belongs to the office that owner is the user signed in 
Only this user can have the option to edit the record.

And this is build for one user (one owner) per office. If they are more I must change it again.

Anyway now I want to do the Edit button but only for the user owners as I explained and need some help.

I thought a nice idea to add to the model Events this code

```
public function scopeInMyOffice($query, $me, $gid)
{
    return $query->join('offices', function ($join) use ($me) {
        $join->on('events.foffice_id', '=', 'office.id')
             ->where('owner_id', $me);
    })->where('event.id', $gid);
}
```

to check every row if it happens but that didnt work.

```
@if( count($event->InMyOffice(Auth::user()->id, $event->id)) > 0)
   <a href="{{ route('event.edit', [$event->id]) }}" class="btn btn-xs btn-info">Edit</a>
@endif
```

So I am stuck and need some help.

Comment: i think it needs to be `where('offices.owner_id',$me);` not `where('owner_id',$me);`

Comment: #Wreigh It didnt change anything. 
In the 2nd scope (InMyOffice) how can make a boolean result and not numeric.  I mean if the event has an office of the user to give true else false. With that result i could show an edit button if true in the index view.